# Cannot find role db_datareader

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2017

I am logged in as sa (double checked it in my session with select suser_name()).

I have created a login `cards_login_generator`, and the same-named user on the database [cards]. I want to permit this user to create logins,users, and make them members to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`.

I've granted `ALTER ANY LOGIN/USER` and it works. Now the time comes for:

`grant alter on role::[db_datareader] to cards_login_generator`

which fails with:

> Cannot find the role 'dbo.db_datareader', because it does not exist or
> you do not have permission.

I have searched exhaustively around but cannot imagine any reason for this message. The role is a (probably undeletable?) database role, and I am sa so no permission issue could be the case. Why does this fail?

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014354) - 14.0.2042.3 (X64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/318175/10832), modifying membership in a fixed database role requires the modifying principal to be a member of the `db_owner` fixed database role.

Here's a test-bed to show how this works.  First off, we'll create a login that has permission to create other logins, then we'll add that login to our `[Test]` database where we'll create a user for the login, and grant that *user* permission to alter users and roles.

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [user_creator_test] 
WITH 
    PASSWORD = N'SomeExceptionally
StrongPassword5%'
    , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english
    , DEFAULT_DATABASE = [Test];

GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO [user_creator_test];
GO

USE [Test];
GO
CREATE USER [user_creator_test]
FOR LOGIN [user_creator_test]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];

GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO [user_creator_test];
GRANT ALTER ANY ROLE TO [user_creator_test];
GO
```

Next, we'll impersonate the new *login* and attempt to create a new login and user, and add that user to the fixed database roles, `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'user_creator_test';

CREATE LOGIN [test_login] 
WITH PASSWORD = N'SomeCrazyHardToGuessPasswords27%'
    , DEFAULT_DATABASE = [Test]
    , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english;

CREATE USER [test_login_user]
FOR LOGIN [test_login]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test_login_user];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [test_login_user];

REVERT;
```

The `ALTER ROLE` statements above fail, reporting this error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 83
> Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 84
> Cannot alter the role 'db_datawriter', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

However, if we make the `[user_creator_test]` a member of the `db_owner` role in our `[Test]` database, then re-run the test, it succeeds:

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [user_creator_test];
GO

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'user_creator_test';
SELECT USER_NAME(), DB_NAME();

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test_login_user];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [test_login_user];

REVERT;
SELECT USER_NAME();
GO
```

This query displays database role membership:

```
SELECT 
      [role]            = dpr.[name]
    , [member]          = dpm.[name]
FROM 
    [sys].[database_principals]                 dpm
    INNER JOIN [sys].[database_role_members]    drm ON dpm.[principal_id]           = drm.[member_principal_id]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[database_principals]      dpr ON drm.[role_principal_id]      = dpr.[principal_id]
ORDER BY 
      [role]
    , [member];
```

Results:

| role | member |
| --- | --- |
| db_datareader | test_login_user |
| db_datawriter | test_login_user |
| db_owner | dbo |
| db_owner | user_creator_test |

Cleanup:

```
USE [master];
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [sys].[server_principals] sp
    WHERE sp.[name] = N'test_login'
)
BEGIN
    DROP LOGIN [test_login];
    PRINT N'Dropped login [test_login]';
END
GO

USE [Test];
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [sys].[database_principals] dp
    WHERE dp.[name] = N'test_login_user'
)
BEGIN
    DROP USER [test_login_user];
    PRINT N'Dropped user [test_login_user]';
END
GO

USE [master];
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [sys].[server_principals] sp
    WHERE sp.[name] = N'user_creator_test'
)
BEGIN
    DROP LOGIN [user_creator_test];
END
GO

USE [Test];
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [sys].[database_principals] dp
    WHERE dp.[name] = N'user_creator_test'
)
BEGIN
    DROP USER [user_creator_test];
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) doc, in order to be able to alter the membership of a fixed database role a user must also be member of the `db_owner` on the database:

> Additionally, to change the membership in a fixed database role you
> need:
>
> - Membership in the `db_owner` fixed database role